# How can I make a overline text decoration longer?

Tags: html, css

Im working on a navigation bar and was having some trouble creating a custom overline effect on the text. Ive figured out how to make the overline text decoration thicker but im trying to figure out how to make it longer.

The overline automatically adjust its width to however long the text is, but im trying to make the line longer than the text if possible. Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

http://outsidethelp.wix.com/otlclothing#!home/mainPage

If you could help I'd greatly appreciate it

Thank You

Comment: This is not a text decoration style, but a style of one of the text containers. The effect can be achieved with `border-top` variation or `padding-top` like in the link.

Comment: Could you provide some CSS to create the line please?

Comment: There are some ways to create this. Here is one http://jsfiddle.net/Ym7pQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your text in a `<div>` tag (or if any other element is already wrapping it, you can use it to), and then set a `border-top` for it. The width of the top border will be the width of the div.

HTML:

```
<div class="overline">
    <span>text text text<span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overline {
    width: 100px;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense but would it work for a nav bar and be able to be applied with a hover effect?

Comment: It should. If you have text inside some `<li>`s, select all the `<li>` in your css and apply a width and a border-top. And for applying it only on hover, just add `:hover` to your selector (in the example above, it would be `.overline:hover`).

Answer (score 0):

First create a div for the text wheres it's gonna be the decoration

for explample

```
<div id="content"><p>your text<p></div>
```

after that with css afect the width of the div and put a border:

```
#content{ border: solid 1px black; width:200px;}
```

I think that can help.

Comment: Will this work applied to a navigation bar? Could apply this same style to a list item?

Thank you for your quick response

Comment: yes it's gonna work, but you will need to use relative units. Or if you don't want to use that, why not bootstrap? And use the grid system, you will solve your problem and you will have a nice responsive menu

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a starting point

```
nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/549tP/1/)

I added an last:child so that you don't have a remainder right border hanging out there

Answer (score 0):

Could this help

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><p>Home</p></a>
<a href="#"><p>Page One</p></a>
<a href="#"><p>Page Two</p></a>
<a href="#"><p>The Last Page</p></a>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    padding-top:20px;
    width:150px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    border-top:#FFF thick solid;
}

p:hover {
    border-top:#F00 thick solid;
}
```

Pb